# how can I load russian(cyrillic, utf-8) text from message_ru_RU.properties in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, localization

I have scheduler. Each 5 sec I get some items from DB and send push notifications to android. But Text in this notifications in Rusian language. In feature we wand support different languages, and now i tried create some templates. I have property file for message templates: `messages_ru_RU.properties` and I have string in this file:  `notification.message=%s. На сумму: %s. Карта: %s`

I need load this String from property and repalse `%s` to my values. Now I create config an service:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {

  @Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("ru");
    slr.setDefaultLocale(defaultLocale);
    return slr;
  }
  @Bean
  public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600); //refresh cache once per hour
    return messageSource;
  }
}
```

and service:

```
@Component
public class MessageByLocaleServiceDefault implements MessageByLocaleService {

  private final MessageSource messageSource;

  @Autowired
  public MessageByLocaleServiceDefault(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSource = messageSource;
  }

  @Override
  public String getMessage(String id) {
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    return messageSource.getMessage(id, null, locale);
  }
}
```

and I try load string from property like this:

```
String messagePlaceholder = messageByLocaleService.getMessage("notification.message");
```

But I see this:

[image]

My question - how can I load russian(cyrillic, utf-8) text from message.properties in spring boot?

My property file saved in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: The problem could be in your IDE. Could you check that evaluated expresstion represents UTF8 encoding? Please try to save message to a file with UTF8 encoding set up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to also set the `MessageSource` encoding properly by configuring the [`setDefaultEncoding()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractResourceBasedMessageSource.html#setDefaultEncoding-java.lang.String-) property:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); // Add this
    return messageSource;
}
```

According to the API documentation, the default is ISO-8859-1:

> Default is none, using the `java.util.Properties` default encoding: ISO-8859-1.

---

Also, be aware that `SessionLocaleResolver` only works for user sessions. If you're going to use the `MessageSource` in combination with a scheduled task, it's not going to work.

Comment: Oh, yes, a friend! Thank you! You saved 4 hours of time!

Comment: "If you're going to use the  MessageSource in combination with a scheduled task, it's not going to work." - can you advise which way I should look in order to properly implement such a task?

Comment: Well, you're passing the locale in the `messageSource.getMessage()`. I assume that you stored the user locale somewhere in a database to be able to send a push notification to a certain user. In that case, you'll have to pass the user locale from the database to the `messageSource.getMessage()` call.

Comment: This answer does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following:

- idea file encoding (Default encoding for properties file should be UTF-8)
- code configuration ResourceBundleMessageSource call method setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")